# How to extract mini-dataframes from an existing one based on certain condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Assuming a df as follows

```
col1    col2
1   1
1   2
1   4
1   6
1   7
1   8
1   24
1   23
1   24
1   1
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   1
1   3
1   2
2   2
2   3
2   4
2   5
2   5
2   6
2   9
2   15
2   16
2   19
2   24
2   1
2   3
2   2
2   1
2   2
2   2
2   3
2   3
```

I would like to do kind of groupby on `col1` and check if in `col2` numbers 1, 2, 3 occur after 24. If yes, the values related to these must be stored as separate dataframes, preferably as follows:

df1:

```
col1    col2
1   1
1   1
1   1
2   1
2   1
```

df2:

```
col1    col2
1   2
1   2
2   2
2   2
2   2
```

df3:

```
col1    col2
1   3
1   3
2   3
2   3
2   3
```

The dataframes: df1, df2, df3 have been created from the values that occur after 24 in `col2`

**Edit 1:**
In the df, there is an instance where in the `col2` a 23 is present between two 24s. In such a case as well, it must check that value, and if it's either 1, 2, or 3, it must be assigned to their respective dataframes

Comment: can use `df1=df[df[df.col2.eq(24)].index[0]:][df.col2.eq(1)]`

Comment: Hey @Shijith, I tried your suggestion, and it works fine for 1s that occur after 24, but it doesn't work for 2s and 3s. Maybe you can run and see it your side once and check it against the output desired and see what I mean as it is difficult for me to explain it in words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Iterate through each group of groupby `for _, group in df.groupby('col1')`
2. Find the original index for the first occurrence of `24` on each group using `group.index.get_loc(group[group.col2.eq(24)].index[0])`
3. Subset each `group` from index found on previous step to the end `group[indexfound: ]`
4. From the subsetted data frame find the occurrences of 1,2 and 3  `[group.col2.eq(1/2/3)]`  and save each to separate data frames

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1','col2'])
df2= df1.copy()
df3 = df1.copy()
for _, group in df.groupby('col1'):
    df1=df1.append(group[group.index.get_loc(group[group.col2.eq(24)].index[0]):][group.col2.eq(1)])
    df2=df2.append(group[group.index.get_loc(group[group.col2.eq(24)].index[0]):][group.col2.eq(2)])
    df3=df3.append(group[group.index.get_loc(group[group.col2.eq(24)].index[0]):][group.col2.eq(3)])
```

Comment: Yes, I did that. But for value 2 in `col1` it is capturing 2s and 3s that occur before 24 aswell

Comment: @zeeman, do you want to check wthr the immediate value after 24 is 1,2,or 3 , or all  occurrence of 1,2 and 3 after the first occurrence of 24? above code is for the later.

Comment: For instance: I do a groupby on `col1`, and for the 1 in `col1`, i check the values in `col2` that occur after 24, and if they are 1, 2, 3, then a separate df for each is to be formed and this has to be applied to all the different numbers that occur in `col1`

Comment: Works. Thanks. Could you add comments for what is happening in the for loop so that I can understand it better?